# How to convert a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a MultiIndex DataFrame:

```
                                c       o       l       u
major       timestamp                       
ONE         2019-01-22 18:12:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:13:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:14:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:15:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:16:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008

TWO         2019-01-22 18:12:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:13:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:14:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:15:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 
            2019-01-22 18:16:00 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008 0.00008
```

I want to generate a NumPy array from this DataFrame with a 3-dimensional, given the dataframe has 15 categories in the major column, 4 columns and one time index of length 5. I would like to create a numpy array with a shape of **(4,15,5)** denoting **(columns, categories, time_index)** respectively.

should create an array:

```
array([[[8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05],
        [8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05]],

       [[8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05],
        [8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05]],

       [[8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05],
        [8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05]],

       [[8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05],
        [8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05, 8.e-05]]])
```

One used to be able to do this with pd.Panel:

```
panel = pd.Panel(items=[columns], major_axis=[categories], minor_axis=[time_index], dtype=np.float32)
...
```

**How would I be able to most effectively accomplish this with a multi index dataframe?**
**Thanks**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using `xarray`?

```
res = df.to_xarray().to_array()
```

Result is an array of shape (4, 15, 5)

In fact the docs now [recommend this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Panel.html) as an alternative to pandas `Panel`. Note that you must have the `xarray` package installed.

Comment: Note, that this method may be very slow for large dataframes in some cases. I tried this with a dataframe with millions of cells. Depending on which variable I had in the column and which in the rows the time was a few seconds in one case, but I stopped the execution after ~20 minutes in the other.

Comment: This is the best solution by far.

Comment: The  `to_xarray` function got reimplemented in xarray 0.16.2 . It is now orders of magnitude faster than it was before.

Answer (score 16):

Since `df.values` is a `(15*100, 4)`-shaped array, you can call `reshape` to make it a `(15, 100, 4)`-shaped array:

```
arr = df.values.reshape(15, 100, 4)
```

Then call `transpose` to rearrange the order of the axes:

```
arr = arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

Now `arr` has shape `(4, 15, 100)`.

---

Using `reshape/transpose` is ~960x faster than `to_xarray().to_array()`:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(15*100, 4)), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(15), range(100)], names=['A','B']), columns=list('colu'))

In [22]: %timeit arr = df.values.reshape(15, 100, 4).transpose(2, 0, 1)
3.31 µs ± 23.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit df.to_xarray().to_array()
3.18 ms ± 24.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [25]: 3180/3.31
Out[25]: 960.7250755287009
```

Comment: Note, that this only works for fully orthogonal cases, ie when you have all combinations of the multi-index, and that is sorted in the proper order. Xarray is much slower, but also more robust.

Comment: The to_xarray function got reimplemented in xarray 0.16.2 . It is now orders of magnitude faster than it was before.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have different length for minor axis, you may try this:

```
df.unstack().ffill().bfill().stack().values.reshape(*df.index.levshape,-1)
```

still seems awkward through, why Panel was deprecated anyway?

Comment: Panel was deprecated because the ppl behind pandas only wanted two classes to maintain, Dataframe and Series, instead of three, and they figured multi-indexed Dataframes could do anything Panels could do in theory (in practice there's definitely a learning curve to map Panels operations to their equivalent multi-indexed Dataframe operations).