# How can I reshape my dataframe into a 3-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My dataframe contains a multivariate time series per user id. The first column `id` is the user id (there are N users), the second `dt` is the date (each user has T days worth of data, i.,e T rows for each user) and the other columns are metrics (basically, each column is a time series per id.) Here's a code to recreate a similar dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

N=5
T=100

dfs=[]
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=T).tolist()

for id in range(N):
    test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    test['dt'] = datelist
    test['id']=id
    dfs.append(test)


dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```

The output would look something like this, where 'A','B' and so on are metrics (like total purchases):

|  | A | B | C | D | dt | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 58 | 3 | 52 | 5 | 2023-07-05 14:34:12.852460 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 34 | 28 | 88 | 2023-07-06 14:34:12.852460 | 0 |
| 2 | 27 | 98 | 74 | 81 | 2023-07-07 14:34:12.852460 | 0 |
| 3 | 96 | 13 | 7 | 52 | 2023-07-08 14:34:12.852460 | 0 |
| 4 | 80 | 69 | 22 | 12 | 2023-07-09 14:34:12.852460 | 0 |

I want to transform this data into a numpy matrix X, of shape N x T x F, where N is the number of users, T is the number of days in the time series (T is constant for all ids) and F is the number of metrics (in the example above, F=4.)

This means that X[0] returns a TxF array, that should look exactly like the output of `dfs.query('id==0')[['A','B','C','D']].values`

So far, I've tried using `pivot` and `reshape` but the elements in the final matrix are not arranged as I would like. Here's what I've tried:

```
# Pivot the dataframe
df_pivot = dfs.sort_values(['id','dt']).pivot(index='id', columns='dt')

# Get the values from the pivot table
X = df_pivot.values.reshape(dfs['id'].nunique(), -1, len([x for x in dfs.columns if x not in ['dt','id']]))
```

If I do `X[0]`, the result I get it:

```
[58,  6, 27, 96],
[80, 65, 41, 39],
[30, 26, 38, 13],
[50, 60, 60, 73],
...
```

From which you can see that the result is not what I would want. This is what I need:

```
[58,  3, 52,  5],
[ 6, 34, 28, 88],
[27, 98, 74, 81],
[96, 13,  7, 52],
...
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by id then for each unique id export the metrics as numpy array inside a list comprehension

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'dt']).sort_index()
np.array([g.values for _, g in df.groupby(level=0)])
```

---

```
array([[[58,  3, 52,  5],
        [ 6, 34, 28, 88],
        [27, 98, 74, 81],
        [96, 13,  7, 52],
        [80, 69, 22, 12]]])
```

Comment: Does this scale easily? N is usually around 300k in my case

Comment: I think it does

Answer (score 1):

Note that numpy array will only contain arrays of similar shapes.

Assumming this is the case you could do:

```
r = sum(df.id == 0)
c = df.shape[1] - 2
arr = df.drop(columns = ['dt', 'id']).values.reshape(-1, r, c)

arr[0]
array([[58,  3, 52,  5],
       [ 6, 34, 28, 88],
       [27, 98, 74, 81],
       [96, 13,  7, 52],
       [80, 69, 22, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that there are exactly the same `T` number of timestamp for each id (and moreover, that they are the same timestamps, I guess, otherwise, it makes no sense), then you could simply

```py
dfs.sort_values(['id', 'dt']).drop(['id', 'dt'], axis=1).values.reshape(N, -1, F)
```

Note that I assume you know `N` and `F`. If you don't you may use `T` also. One of the 3 `.reshape(N, T, F)` can be replaced by `-1`.

Any way, you can compute them, even if all you have is `dfs`

```py
F=len(dfs.columns)-2 # minus dt and id
N=len(dfs.id.unique())
T=len(dfs.dt.unique())
```

The 2 latter are slower to compute than the first. So, use `F` and one of `N` and `T` for `reshape`, preferably the one you know in advance if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I add a second answer, rather than edit my first, since this answer is completely different from my previous one, and is not just an improvement of it.

An alternative answer to my previous one, inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615992/20037042) — about roughly the same question, but for dataframe with indexes; but you just have to do that to get into the same situation

```py
np.moveaxis(dfs.set_index(['id', 'dt']).to_xarray().to_array().to_numpy(), 0, 2)
```

`set_index` send us to the situation of the linked question.
`to_xarray().to_array()` is the answer to that question.
Since it doesn't still return a numpy array, `to_numpy()` does it.
And then, since it returns a 3d array with the index axis at the end, and you want them first `moveaxis` does that (`moveaxis` is basically free, anyway. It doesn't move any data).

## Some timing comparison

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| This | 5.2 ms |
| My other answer (sort) | 2.02 ms |
| Shubham's (a mix: index then sort) | 5.0 ms |

But when scaling a bit (not as much as what you said in a comment, with N=300k. But just N=5k), timings change

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| This | 142 ms |
| My other (sort) | 165 ms |
| Shubham's | 625 ms |

(scaling more, doesn't change these ratio, since, after a while, all 3 methods are O(N)).

So after a certain size, this method doesn't cost more than `sort` based method.
Shubham's doesn't scale well with axis N, because of the pure python compound list (I haven't tested, but I am pretty sure it scales as well as others along other axis)

## Robustness to missing rows

And it has a huge advantage: if, by accident, one of the timestamp is missing for one of the id, it still works (filling with `nan`), while my other answer, as well as Shubham's would faild, since they both rely on the number of rows for each id being identical.
(My `sort` method, because `reshape` assumes that there are exactly N×T×F values. Or at least, with -1, a factor of T×F, but if that factor is not N×T×F, then it is even worse: it will seem to work, but values would be shifted
Shubham's because `np.array(...)` on an array of 2d arrays assumes that all those arrays have the same shape.)

And, sure, you said that this was the case. But any coder feels uncomfortable when using this kind of asumptions. We want to be a bit defensive.
And since, anyway, it doesn't cost more, I would go with this method (I insist on "it doesn't cost more", because the older post I've linked presented this as a tradeof: cost more, but more reliable; but since that, as said in one of the comments, `xarray` was improved. To the point that, today, it isn't a tradeoff.

To be accurate, if I say "it doesn't cost more" and not jump to "it costs less", it is because, among the random timings I did, for a few (may 1/4), it was my `sort/reshape` method that was the faster. But within the same 10% margin we have on the other direction.

So nowadays, the tradeoff is not about timing. It is about "need to be 100% positive that no rows are missing" vs "need a package install" (since `.to_xarray()` needs a `pip install xarray` to work.